# Google Chat API: Async Response to Dialog

Tags: google-chat, google-chat-api

I use slash command with dialog option enabled.

My goal is to provide user ability to search some object. Since search is not a fast action, I want to print in Dialog something like 'Please await'. And when search will be over - update Dialogs content with results.

I found mention about similar action here: https://developers.google.com/chat/how-tos/dialogs#respond_to_a_dialog_with_a_text_message_or_a_card .

But I cannot understand what format of message should be defined.

Could someone provide example?

Problem is to update dialog asyncronously, updating by responses works well.

Comment: Google team, please help. You are monitoring these tags, right? Thanks